# 1:n or n:m, Table Relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables: Sentence and FollowUp.

Sentence simply stores string sentences and a few metadata columns.
FollowUp saves which sentences are followed up by certain other sentences. So, in my followUp table, I reference two sentenceIds (sentenceFrom, sentenceTo).

My question: Is the relationship between these two tables 1:n or n:m?

My explanation would be the following:
1 line out of Sentence has mostly two references in FollowUp (one sentenceTo, one sentenceFrom).
1 line out of FollowUp also references more than one line in Sentence.

So n:m right, but what intermediate-table should I use between those two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an n:m relationship, but you don't need another table, because both entities involved in the relationship are `Sentence`.

In other words, given that an n:m relationship needs an intermediate table to record the pairings, your `FollowUp` table serves as that intermediate table.

Answer (score 0):

Data structure-wise this is a linked list. As such there can be one or two relationships. There would be:

1. > Sentence - Follows - Sentence
2. > Sentence - Is followed by - Sentence (*Optional*)

When you have both relationships you have a doubly linked list.

Based on your description these are both 1 - 1 relationships so you can actually just put them on the `Sentence` table e.g.

> Sentence (value, metadataColumn1, ..., metadataColumnN, previousSentence, nextSentence)